# 'Communication Error' When I Query Solr, Only in IE?

Tags: apache, internet-explorer, solr

When I try to ping Solr, I get a failure only in IE.

```
if (!$solr->ping()) {
    echo 'service not available';
}
```

The connection is identical when using `var_dump` in both IE and other browsers. It's running on the standard Solr port, localhost, and the path is correct. Unsure how a different browser would affect a connection to Solr.

Solr Specification Version: 1.4.1.2011.09.12.09.25.21

Comment: IE7 & IE8 tested. IE9 untested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly enough, it seems that `allow_url_fopen` not being enabled was the root cause of this issue. Unrelated, seemingly, so I'd assume the issue was with the WordPress plugin used. I'd have to guess some odd implementation made this fail silently and cause issues only in IE.

Probably too specific to my case to help others, but thought I'd share.